# Neokree Materialtabs tab title translations error

Tags: android

I'm using on my app Neokree Materialtabs. I can not translate tab title. I tired so many strings codes. Android Studio building to apk and don't gives me error but when I launch app it stopping by self.

Code tabs title:

```
private String[] tabs = {"Home","Category","Favourite"};
```

And:

```
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // when user do a swipe the selected tab change
            tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for(String tab_name:tabs)
    {
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTab()
                .setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(MainActivity.this)
                );
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MaterialTabListener {

    MaterialTabHost tabHost;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private String[] tabs = {"Home","Category","Favourite"};
    Toolbar toolbar;
    String strMessage;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_intertestial_id));
        mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onAdLoaded();
                if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitial.show();
                }
            }
        });


        tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager );
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // when user do a swipe the selected tab change
                tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }
        });

        for(String tab_name:tabs)
        {
            tabHost.addTab(
                    tabHost.newTab()
                    .setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(MainActivity.this)
                    );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public Fragment getItem(int num) {

            switch (num) {
            case 0:
                return new HomeFragment();
            case 1:
                return new CategoryFragment();
            case 2:
                return new FavouriteFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!hasFocus) {
                    MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenuItem);
                    searchView.setQuery("", false);
                }
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Constant.SHOP_SEARCH=arg0;
                Intent intsearch=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Search.class);
                startActivity(intsearch);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
    {       
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) 
        {
        case R.id.about: 
            Intent intab=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intab);
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // Toast.makeText(appContext, "BAck", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            alert.setMessage(R.string.quit);

            alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int whichButton) {

                    finish();
                }



            });

            alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.rate,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    final String appName = getPackageName();//your application package name i.e play store application url
                    try {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                                        + appName)));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                                        + appName)));
                    }

                }
            });
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

I tried this codes:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.menu_home)
```

And this:

```
getString(R.string.menu_home)
```

I wanna do like this but not working:

```
private String[] tabs = {getString(R.string.menu_home),getString(R.string.menu_cat),getString(R.string.menu_fav)};
```

Also I tried like this:

```
private String[] tabs = {getResources().getString(R.string.menu_home),getResources().getString(R.string.menu_cat),getResources().getString(R.string.menu_fav)};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `getResources().getString(R.string.menu_home);`

Comment: I tired also this. Android studio don't gives me error but when I launch app it stopping.

Comment: Then please post your logcat

Comment: E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.

Comment: That problem is nothing to do with your question. Make sure you have this permission in your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>`